# C-style assertion handlers

Tags: c, assert, assertions

There are several ways to make dynamic checks in complex software:

1. assert.h implementation `assert( expression_that_must_be_true );`
2. Linux kernel style:

   ```
   if (in_interrupt())
           BUG();
   ```

If checked condition's value is not as expected, some bug handler is called.

For example:

```
#define BUG( ) \
{ \
 printf("BUG found (function %s file %s line %d)\n", __FUNCTION__, \
                    __FILE__, __LINE__); \
 exit(1); \
}
```

Even in this simplest implementation of bug handling some bugs can be hidden (as "there are no programs without bugs"). This bug can lead to recursive call of this bug handler (from printf, for example). If there are bug conditions still, bug handler will be called again and again, until stack is overflowed. In worst case, developer even will not see any messages (for example, if bug is in the beginning of printf).

Question is: What are good techniques of avoiding recursive calls in bug handlers, while still getting some debug information?

Comment: could be only me, but I didn't get this part: "This bug can lead to recursive call of this bug handler". If you mean the simple BUG() macro above, can you give an example where it would be called recursively? Are you assuming that `printf` or `exit` could be buggy and therefore attempt to use `BUG()` themselves?

Comment: Yes, exactly so. BUG can be called from printf. Thank you, I've edited question to clarify this.

Comment: I'd at least use a funky `do{...}while()` for the definition of BUG().

Comment: I can see your point of you were calling one of your functions from within `BUG()`. However, if you are calling a library function, they don't know anything about your macro, so no chance of a recursive call. Perhaps the example you are using to illustrate is too contrived. Anyway, a generic answer: to avoid recursion, only call functions that you know for a fact don't use your the macro. All of the libstd... functions fall into that category.

Comment: For example, [printk implementation](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/printk.c) uses recursion_bug variable to handle recursion: see vprintk.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a global variable to the max depth to avoid recursive calls.

debug.c

```
unsigned Debug_MaxDepth = 5;
```

debug.h

```
#define BUG( ) \
{ \
  if (Debug_MaxDepth > 0) { \
    Debug_MaxDepth--; 
    printf("BUG found ...\n"); \
  } \
exit(1); \
}
```